# How do you adjust a windshield sprayer?

Tags: windshield-washer

One of the sprayers on my car misses the windshield completely. How can I adjust it to point in the right direction?

My car is a 2002 Subaru Legacy GT, but I've run into this problem with many cars.

Answer (score 4):

I use a pin board, needle, a finish nail or whatever I have in the garage. Put in the sprayers holes and correct alignment. Done! Make sure to not push any object to far as it can damage inner tube and start to leak!

Comment: They don't appear to be that adjustable. The hole is more of a slot than a hole. I tried poking a needle into it in case there was an obstruction but nothing changed.

Comment: There should be a hole in the middle of the slot - the slot should taper towards the back.

Answer (score 1):

All of my cars have had to have the nozzles adjusted at one time or other - especially after cleaning. There is always a hole or a V shaped slot that you can tweak up or down.

Answer (score 0):

The pin or needle works well, but as a car ages then parts freeze up.  You might need to free the nozzles in their housing by adding a drop of WD40 or crc556 to break the adjustable part loose of anything sticking them to the housing.

Then use a pin down the throat of the jet nozzle as leverage and an aiming tool.